# Match everything except every given combination

Tags: regex, oracle

Given string, for example `abbbabf`

given piece, for example `ab`

Needed, that remove all characters, except every pieces, that is from `abbbabf` must get result: `abab`

How should be regex pattern for this ?

**Edit**

Lets take php as example

Its simply to remove everyting, except piece, if piece is just one symbol, that is if piece is `a`, must do

```
$str = "abbbabf"; 
echo preg_replace("#[^a]#", "", $str);
```

and result is `aa`

But how to make this when piece is more than one symbol, I have no idea...

Please dont give solutions such as:

```
preg_match_all("#ab#", $str, $a);
echo implode($a[0]);
```

Thanks

PS. I need make this In ORACLE database and if I find solution (one pattern) without procedure handling, will be cool.

Comment: There is a chance this question will be put "on hold" because you did not post your attempt at solving it.

Comment: Why must is be a (single?) regex?

Comment: Because I need just one pattern for `regexp_replace` function. Not need step by step handling. This one works of course, but one pattern is just for interest

Comment: Ah, okay, you're not solving an actual problem...

Comment: Actually, I have an actual problem :)
I need make this In ORACLE database and if I find solution (one pattern) without procedure handling, will be cool. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Then please explain your actual problem properly, including the regex implementation you're working with. Most DBMS engines support less than the average PCRE engine (like the PHP engine you gave an example for).

Comment: I understand the problem completely: remove everything from a string that doesn't match `word`.

Comment: @r3mus, I understand it just fine: but the hidden requirement of using Oracle's regex implementation means no look-arounds (i.e. your solution doesn't work then). What I meant by "explain your actual problem properly" is that the OP should not give PHP examples while s/he is targeting some other language.

Comment: @BartKiers fair enough - but in this case, lookarounds are the only way it's going to work, so in a sense the question that was asked was answered. That said, like you say, it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following can do it using capture groups rather than assertions:

```
$str = "helloababblolobbbabf";
             ^^^^        ^^ 
echo preg_replace("#.*?(ab|$)#", "$1", $str); 

// Output: ababab
```

[RegExr](http://regexr.com?37j3u)

Since you say you're actually working in Oracle, you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(input, '.*?(ab|$)', '\1')
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b2093/1/0)

Comment: Again though, since this is Oracle, it's not going to work :|

Comment: Which part doesn't work? I don't use Oracle so I can't claim it **does** work, but [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/oracle.html) suggests that Oracle allows **back references** `\1` through `\9` as well as **lazy quantifiers** - the 2 things I assumed might not work when I read your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The expression you need to use is this:

`((?<=ab|^).*?(?=ab|$))`

From the string, `abbbabfasdfsdfsdfab` `ababab` is returned.

See it in action: http://regex101.com/r/nT8mC1

**Caveat** as Bart points out in a comment, Oracle doesn't implement much of the PCRE standard, and as such this simply won't work. You'll have to look at implementing some sort of capture set where you can *capture* the string you want and rebuild it with `implode` (which you don't want to do apparently).

**Edit** added suggestion for conditional from comments.

Comment: Thanks, but if string is: `abbbabaaasd` not works correct, or I am not understand something ?

Comment: @OTARIKI, correct - this fails for any input that does not both start and end with the pattern `ab`. A small change to `((?<=ab|^).*?(?=ab|$))` probably works although variable length lookbehinds are supported even less.

Comment: You're right - updated regex with details. While this won't help someone using Oracle, it will anyone using fully PCRE regex.